# Sheep eating grass with fences on it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, Sheep used to be able to eat grass even if there was a fence on top of it. But recently a friend of mine made a wool farm, and the sheep aren't eating the grass that has a fence on it. Is this still possible or am I just REALLY unlucky?

Comment: When you say "used to eat grass" what do you mean? Do you mean a different version? If so what was that version?

Comment: Yes I mean an older version, but i'm not sure which version. All I remember is that, like a few years ago, I made a sheep farm underground next to my wheat farm, and one of the corner pieces of dirt grew before the rest since it was closest to water, then the sheep walked up and ate it no problem.

Comment: Are the sheep stuck inside a fence or are they next to it? Sheep never walk exactly to the edge of a fence on their own, only when pushed. Maybe that's your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they changed it because it was unrealistic. I noticed it too. I do know that there people who have asked for more realistic features. If it affects your wool production you can try expanding a bit. 8x8 works best for me.